# Problems with l0phtcrack

Tags: penetration-test, password-cracking

I recently wrote a website for my company and have been asked to Pen test it as well as the server. Have run SQL map and no vulnerabilities there, however I want to check if my hash and things are good enough as well as any vulnerabilities to the server its self. When I trained we had a working copy of L0phtcrack. Downloaded the trial to see if it was still as good.

I set it to the following:

> ```
> >  · Retrieve passwords by sniffing the local network   · Perform
> > 'Strong' password audit   · Display domain password belongs to   ·
> > Display passwords when audited   · Display password hashes   · Display
> > time spent auditing each password   · Give visible notification when
> > done auditing   · Show method used to crack password
> ```

However this gets me:

> No encrypted passwords were imported. The l0phtcrack 6 wizard cannot
>   continue. Please try another password retrieval.

So I run the wizard again to check my local PC just to see if there is a problem, And I get the same response I cannot do anything.

So I have two questions:

1: What am I doing wrong? It has been a fair few years since I properly pen tested and am very rusty.

2: Anything better out there currently to detected and crack packets? I know about wireshark for sniffing.

---update---

I do now realize that it has stopped being supported and developed, in that case good alternatives for packet sniffing and cracking

Comment: Why is your company doing this in the first place? **An outside pentester should have been hired**!

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used l0phtcrack in a long time, but I would suggest trying out [John the Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/).

I would also recommend grabbing one of the community enhanced version, for windows, here is a direct link http://www.openwall.com/john/g/john179j5w.zip.

I should also mention that you will want to grab a decent wordlist as the built in one may not be enough. There are a few good wordlists to start with at https://wiki.skullsecurity.org/Passwords.

The JTR syntax can be a bit confusing, but it is really powerful if you want to really get into password cracking.

Comment: Keep getting "no password hashes loaded see FAQ" have tired --worldlist==password.lst and keep getting password file required

Comment: do you have a file containing your hashes?

Comment: It came with password.lst, I made a simple txt called crack me with user:hashhere in it to test it out and its just not doign anything.

Comment: What kind of hashes are you trying to crack?

Comment: You can use the `--force` option, described http://www.openwall.com/john/doc/OPTIONS.shtml to force it to use a particular hash type.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13109/discussion-between-casey-and-marriott81)